# Transform an Irish grid reference (29903) into UK grid reference (27700) on insert

Tags: postgresql, coordinates, coordinate-system

I have an insert script to input several hundred points, however some of the points use the Irish Grid Reference system. I have separated these out however was unsure how to convert or transform? these into 27700 on insert. I have the line below that grabs the UK reference, and the POST_GIS column is set to 27700.

`st_geomfromtext('POINT(" . addslashes($data[6]) . ")',27700)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   ST_Transform(st_geomfromtext('POINT(" . addslashes($data[6]) . ")',29903), 27700)
```

First you create your point in irish system with st_geomfromtext(..., 29903) and then you transform it to another system, in this case 27700. ( I assume that those srids are correct)